# Listing logged in users info from database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web-applications

I'm having real trouble getting any info from my database.
I'm think I am on the right track, but always get this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

In my controller class I've got this method:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Oblig1.Models.User user)
    {
        if (Bruker_i_DB(user) != null)
        {
            Session["User"] = User.ToString();
            ViewBag.LoggedIn = true;
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            Session["User"] = null;
            ViewBag.LoggedIn = false;
            return View();
        }

    }
```

and in the .cshtml file I've got this:

```
@model Oblig1.Models.User
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <title>LoggedInSite</title>
        <p>@Model.Email</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does this make sense to anyone?
after a couple of days I'm starting to get fairly frustrated...

Comment: Makes no sense to me, but you probably want `return View(user);`

Comment: you are not pasising model object to view from action

Comment: Add your view completely please....

Comment: Session["User"] = User.ToString() should be user.ToString() (note lowercase user).

Answer (score 0):

You are never passing the view a model so this line:

```
<p>@Model.Email</p>
```

will always fail with a null reference exception

Comment: I have added user in return View(user) if thats what you mean? still the same error

Comment: Are you doing that in both places where you return the view?

Comment: Also, have you verified that the method parameter `Oblig1.Models.User user` is not null?